# Insert DateTime into SQL Server Using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to insert a datetime value into my SQL database using PHP.

This is my code:

```
$time= date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

$ordersquery= "INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate) VALUES ('{$phonenumber}', '{$time}')";
echo $ordersquery."\n";
```

Whenever I try to execute the code, there is a failure to enter the information into the database that reads:

> INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate) VALUES ('(444) 849-7592',
>   '2015-05-10 12:03:28.000000')
>
> boolean false
>
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.
>
> null

**I've also tried using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and using ISO-8601 format.**

Comment: what data type is `orderDate`?

Comment: orderDate is declared datetime

Comment: I don't know anything about php but I do know sql server. use [Parameterized Queries.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(v=sql.105).aspx) The link provides a php example.

Comment: Use parameterized queries, or risk a visit from [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).   See [PHP examples here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 5):

Try this format instead:

```
$time= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The value to be inserted in *[Datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)* should be in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Comment: This is what the output is when I use 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS   'INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate) VALUES ('(333) 736-4572', '1969196919691969-DecDec-WedWed 1919:DecDec:stst')
boolean false

Comment: @IrisSpik No! Use the part I specified in code section not the explanations below it - I mean this part: `$time= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Here'e the output: INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate) VALUES ('(578) 743-4753', '2015-05-10 13:11:26')
boolean false

Comment: @IrisSpik Check your table to see if the row is actually inserted or not.

Comment: it's not inserting. There was some sample data I inserted into the database before- format of the datetime of the variable in the database looks like this '2015-05-09 12:00:00.000'

Comment: @IrisSpik And what's the type of customerID column in DB?

Comment: The customerID is a unique phone number, declared VarChar14. There is an INSERT statement going to the CustomerInformation table immediately preceding the INSERT statement to the Orders table which is always successful. It reads INSERT INTO CustomerInformation VALUES ('Sheldon', 'Cooper', '(578) 743-4753'). 
boolean true

Comment: @IrisSpik in what you have provided here nothing else seems wrong to me - you may want to double check other stuff: your connection to DB, your columns declarations (make sure customerID is varchar) or you can provide us more code.

Comment: figured it out. My column that was supposed to be an identity was declared as an integer, so it wasn't auto-inserting and was showing up as a null value

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can store timestamp in format  Y-m-d H:m:s.  Other than **Y-m-d H:m:s** It will give an error.

You can set orderDate data type to Varchar and while querying in to database just convert/type cast it to Date format..

Hope this will help or might give you an idea to solve it....

Comment: This is what I get when I use Current_Timestamp:                                 INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate) VALUES ('(333) 736-4572', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
boolean false
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
null

Comment: set orderDate data type to Varchar  while inserting in db and while querying in to db just convert/type cast it to Date format DATE_FORMAT  Y-m-d H:i:s.u

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND NEVER EVER Store date time values as varchar.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, You are right but  iris is trying to store Y-m-d H:i:s.u  in field having data type CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Y-m-d H:m:s , i thnk this is wrong. Data  type Varchar will be just another way to achieve his task...