# what is the date format to insert a date using sqlsrv_query?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I get all rows by this sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql3 , $params, $options );
```

But when I want to insert:

```
$sql2 = 
   "INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, USER_NOM, USER_DATE) 
   VALUES (".$row['USER_ID'].", '".$row['USER_NOM']."','".$row['USER_DATE']->format('Y-m-d h:i:s.v')."')";
```

I get this error:

> Converting the varchar data type to datetime produced an out of range
> value.

This is my `$sql2`:

```
INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, USER_NOM, USER_DATE) VALUES (1,DANI,'2020-07-22 12:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert DateTime into SQL Server Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153619/insert-datetime-into-sql-server-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

- You need to use parameterized statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), the `sqlsrv_query()` function *is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.*
- By default `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, `date`, `time`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset` types will be returned as PHP DateTime objects, but this behaviour can be changed by setting the `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string or at the statement level (more explanations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350489/data-type-differences-between-php-sqlsrv-driver-and-pdo-driver/61352482#61352482)).

You have two options, if you are sure, that date/time values are returned as PHP DateTime objects:

- Pass datetime values as text using unambiguous format (e.g. `2020-07-22T12:00:00.000`)
- Pass datetime values as PHP DateTime objects using extended syntax for parameters for the `sqlsrv_query()` call.

Example (datetime values are passed as text):

```
<?php
// SELECT statement
$sql3  = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql3 , $params, $options);
if ($stmt3 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   

// INSERT statements
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $sql2 = "
        INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, USER_NOM, USER_DATE) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ";
    $params = array(
       $row['USER_ID'], 
       $row['USER_NOM'], 
       $row['USER_DATE']->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v'));
    );
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2 , $params);

}
?>
```

Example (datetime values are passed as PHP DateTime objects):

```
<?php
// SELECT statement
$sql3  = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql3 , $params, $options);
if ($stmt3 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   

// INSERT statements
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $sql2 = "
        INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, USER_NOM, USER_DATE) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ";
    $params = array(
        array($row['USER_ID'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array($row['USER_NOM'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array($row['USER_DATE'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_DATETIME, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME)
    );
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2 , $params);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Datetime`value to be inserted in `Datetime` type , it should be in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

**Note:-** For More Details Please refer this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: I try this but didn´t work  $row['USER_DATE']->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')

Comment: what you have in `$row['USER_DATE']'?

Comment: please convert date  from varchar data type to datetime

Comment: object(DateTime)[1]
      public 'date' => string '2020-07-22 12:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

Comment: This completely ignores the fact that the OP has a huge security flaw here.